# How to enable 'Export to Android Package' in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2012

I have developed a small mobile app with Apache Cordova using Visual Studio 2015. Now I want to make an apk file to install in on my android phone and also an ipa file for iphone. The problem is I couldn't find any option to make the apk file. There is no option available in the settings and properties of the app. Following are the screen shots of the settings and properties of the app.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/78280/visual-studio-publish-android-app-option-not-available), You have to do it via the Archive Manager now.

> So they have removed this option and you have to do it via Archive Manager.